# Strapi: React: Cannot read property 'associations' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, strapi

Currently trying to upload an image and connect it to an existing entry.

The schema of the existing entry is

```
{
      "name": "page rows",
      "description": "",
      "connection": "default",
      "kind": "collectionType",
      "collectionName": "page_rows",
      "attributes": {
        "row": {
          "type": "json"
        },
        "images": {
          "type": "media",
          "multiple": true,
          "required": false,
          "allowedTypes": [
            "images"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

and I upload an image using

```js
export const formatEntryUpload = (file, entryModel, entryID, entryField, entryPlugin = null) => {
  const entryUpload = new FormData();
  entryUpload.append('files', file);
  entryUpload.append('ref', entryModel);
  entryUpload.append('refId', entryID);
  entryUpload.append('field', entryField);
  if(entryPlugin) {
    entryUpload.append('source', entryPlugin);
  }
  return entryUpload;
};
```

where I fill call the function by

```js
formatEntryUpload ( file, "page_rows", id, "images", "users-permissions");
```

however when I do I get the following error.

```
[2021-02-07T21:01:35.334Z] error TypeError: Cannot read property 'associations' of undefined
at /srv/app/node_modules/strapi-connector-mongoose/lib/relations.js:250:43
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at /srv/app/node_modules/strapi-connector-mongoose/lib/relations.js:235:20
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at Function.update [as updateRelations] (/srv/app/node_modules/strapi-connector-mongoose/lib/relations.js:97:68)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at async Object.add (/srv/app/node_modules/strapi-plugin-upload/services/Upload.js:253:17)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at async Object.upload (/srv/app/node_modules/strapi-plugin-upload/services/Upload.js:105:12)
at async Object.upload (/srv/app/node_modules/strapi-plugin-upload/controllers/Upload.js:82:18)
at async /srv/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/middlewares/router/utils/routerChecker.js:70:22
at async module.exports (/srv/app/node_modules/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/config/policies/permissions.js:97:3)
at async /srv/app/node_modules/strapi-utils/lib/policy.js:52:5
[2021-02-07T21:01:35.334Z] debug POST /upload (564 ms) 500
```

The image is successfully uploaded however it is not associated with the entry. What do I need to change to associate the image with the entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change "page_rows" to "page_row"
it helped me

```
formatEntryUpload ( file, "page_rows", id, "images", "users-permissions") => 
formatEntryUpload ( file, "page_row", id, "images", "users-permissions");
```